# Display product loop based on tag only in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to display a product loop in a Collection template on Shopify. I want to pull all products with a specific tag 'Hydrate' to display within the Collection.

The template file is collection.custom.liquid and so far I have the below:

```
{% for product in collection.products %}   
{% if product.tags contains "Hydrate" %} 
 Do Something
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But it doesn't display anything. I have confirmed I do have the tags setup correctly and I'm even using the exact same case sensitivity in case thats a thing.

If someone could point me in the right direction to display products from the tag 'Hydrate' in a custom collection template that would be great! Thanks so much

*EDIT*

I've now altered the code and moved it outside any pagination, and added for each product to the below. It now displays however it keeps displaying the same tags 5 times over on the page. Is there an issue with my syntax? Any ideas?

```
{% for product in collection.products %} 
  {% for product in products %}
    {% if product.tags contains "Hydrate" %} 
        <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

*EDIT 2*

In case anyone else has this same issue in future, the below code is what has ended up working and displays the correct tags, the correct amount of times:

```
{% assign products = collection.products %}
  {% for product in products %}
    {% if product.tags contains "Hydrate" %} 
        <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think you need to create specific collection into backend and filter the products into backend using tag, and show them into page

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, so it might be a pagination issue. For example, there are no product with this tag in the first page but there are in the second one.